# Волосы-колосья-голоса: разница в склонении

Tags: этимология, лексика, грамматика, морфология, склонение

Склонение существительных - головная боль не только для иностранцев, изучающих русский язык, но и для его носителей. Недавно сестра задала такой вопрос: "Почему слова ***"голос"***, ***"колос"*** и ***"волос"*** в единственном числе похожи, но так сильно отличаются во множественном?".

Я попыталась найти ответ в истории русского языка, но пришла к выводу, что все эти существительные, как и сейчас, принадлежали к одному склонению - на o краткое. При этом некогда использовалась форма "волосья". Где-то находила информацию о том, что в суффикс -j- закладывается значение собирательности (вспомним слово "многоголосье"). И все же слова разошлись. Мотивировано ли это как-нибудь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это результат развития категории множественного числа.

Волосы- развилось из праславянского, в древнем языке окончание множ.ч.  было мягким, стало твёрдым - ы.  Вариант волоса - разговорный, волосья - просторечный.

У существительного голос множественное число -голосА - восходит к так называемой форме двойственного числа (из "два голоса" с переносом ударения). Она есть, например, в словах "глаза", "берега". Эта форма, утратив свое исходное значение, сегодня перемешалась с нормативной, зачастую конкурируя с ней. В целом этот процесс стихийный и не поддается строгому научному объяснению. Отсюда - шоферы / шофера, мастера, цеха / цехи.

Распределение фактов, относящихся к именительному множественному у «неодушевленных» между окончаниями -а(-ы) с одной стороны и -ья — с другой проходит по различию семантическому: представления четко обособленных единиц, взятых во множественности, получают окончание -а, множественное число к представлениям совокупного характера - ья: дома, города, пояса, острова, желобѣ,
но колья, сучья, зубья, листья.

Колос + собират. суфф. ij = колосья. Ср. : листья. Но есть и колосЫ (устар. и диалектн.) , а также листЫ (листы бумаги).

Comment: Людмила, большое спасибо!  Подскажите,  пожалуйста,  источник.

Comment: Источник чего? Материала о двойственном числе? http://russkiyyazik.ru/218/  Если нужно подробно, наберите в поисковике "Двойственное число" или "История категории числа". О собирательных сущ. - в материале о значении суффикса-ij-